# Unexpected order for a range sorted with non alpha-numeric characters

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting an unexpected result when I sort a list with Excel or with some VBA (`Range.Sort`). It seems that the hyphen is simply ignored when the text is sorted:

**List sorted with Excel**

```
align-content
align-items
alignment-baseline    << Should be after "align-self"
align-self
animation-delay
```

**The same list sorted with Libre Office**

```
align-content
align-items
align-self
alignment-baseline
animation-delay
```

The documentation doesn't provide any information on this behavior:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB#__toc246836970

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx

So is there any rule behind this behavior ?

Is there an option to sort the list the same way a human would do (as Libre Office does) ?

Comment: What do you consider "the same way a human would"?

Comment: @Comintern, by human I mean the same way Libre Office does, which is likely the same way a sane human would do. I don't see anyone who would place `alignment-baseline` after `align-items` and before `align-self` when asked to order the list.

Comment: Generally, sorting requires so much code I record a macro and amend it. Have you tried  this?

Comment: @Comintern: I presume the meaning is *in actual alphabetical order based on the value of the characters*, which is what I would expect as well. The sort order is clearly wrong; the ordinal (decimal) ASCII values are sorting in the wrong order in items #3 and #4 in the Excel output.

Comment: @KenWhite - Something can only be "clearly wrong" if it doesn't match a specification. If I were sorting strings from a Word document, I'd *expect* it to ignore the hyphens. "Human" isn't a sort order, thus the question asking for clarification.  Although, in my experience humans tend to sort incorrectly *regardless of* the rules they're using.  That's why I prefer computers to sort for me... ;-)

Comment: @Comintern: Um, no. The ordinal values of the characters are relevant, even when sorting as a human. Every value with `align-` as the first six characters should be together, in alpha order determined by the seventh character. The specification for alpha sorting is determined by the value of the characters in order, not by arbitrarily discarding characters for no apparent reason. I can perhaps excuse Word for doing so, if it mistakenly took the hyphen as a word-split at the right margin, but not Excel (which has no reason to hyphenate words at margins and doesn't do so).

Comment: @KenWhite - Um, no. You can't make a blanket statement as to what is "correct" as a sort order.  The "correctness" of a sort order is determined by business rules, and unless you ***ask what the business rule is***, any sort order can be considered arbitrary.

Comment: @Comintern: Nonsense. Unless otherwise specified, the ordinal values of the characters should determine sort order, period. Your *business rules* may determine that a sort other than the default order is required, but there is a standard sort order.  Look at any ASCII chart; there is a **defined order** for each characters based on its ordinal value.

Comment: @KenWhite - Excel gets to decide Excel's business rules.  Everyone else gets to decide their own business rules.  It also defaults to case insensitive (which also isn't ASCII order), and is much more likely to be subject to a business rule than hyphens and apostrophes. Why should a `_` sort between upper and lower case? I prefer to ***ask for the expected behavior before making assumptions***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel ignores hyphens in doing the sort, unless that is the only difference between two words.

One work around is to create a "helper column", replacing the <kbd>hyphen</kbd> (code 45)  with a <kbd>dot</kbd> (code 46).
Sort on the helper column

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",".")
```

I have read someplace that the default sort order has a sequence:

- apostrophe
- hyphen
- space

with the first two generally ignored

That being the case, replacing the <kbd>hyphen</kbd> with a <kbd>space</kbd> might be more logical.

Comment: IIR it also ignores apostrophes.

Comment: @Comintern Yes, it does.  And, if that is an issue, you can apply a similar fix.  Given what I have read regarding the default sort order, it might be better to replace either one of those with a `space`